# JavaMail without a Sender

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

So the question I have is one regarding JavaMail. I want to send an email to different email addresses, but I want the sender to be something like "noreply". However, I can't seem to do this because JavaMail needs an actual email address on both, the sender and the receiver, for it to work.

I could create my own domain and SMTP, but that seems annoying. Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it needs to be a syntactically correct email address eg: example@domain.com, however, it doesn't need to be a real, working address.

Answer (score 4):

If the SMTP server does not do any checks itself (such as checking that the From address you are sending from actually exists and matches the domain name) JavaMail allows you to put whatever address you want. If your SMTP server allows it you can even spoof email addresses of other people easily. So you could set your `From` field to `president@whitehouse.gov` if you want without problems.

Just set it to `no-reply@something.com` to test it out. However you should put a good domain otherwise your emails might get marked as spam by spam filters. Showing the recipients where the email is actually coming from is also a good idea!

Comment: I like this answer, except for the fact that the clients I'm going to be sending the noreply emails to could have gmail, yahoo, etc. I assume that the server on that side is intelligent enough to notice.

Comment: As long as you're not sending spam, and you're sending them from a legitimate source, having 'no-reply' as the username is not an issue. A lot of automated email notifications in fact go out with `no-reply` so it has become a sort of defacto standard. The problem will be if you send them from a fictitious domain which does not exist. The mail servers of most serious email providers might flag that as a suspicious email. Even if you send it from a legitimate domain that does exist, but it does not match the SMTP server's domain some mail servers also detect that and flag it as Phishing.